# What specificity does [class$=" "] and [id*=" "] hold?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

```
[class$=" "]
[class*=" "]
[class^=" "]
```

All of the above (and the ID equivalents) do not seem to follow the standard CSS specificity weight rules.

I made a Codepen to show how odd and conflicting they are. http://codepen.io/mildrenben/pen/myYLmG

Markup

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <p> #idName is more specific than [id*="idName"]. But .className and [class*="className"] seem to be the same specificty.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
  border: solid 5px green;
}

[id*="wrap"] {
  border: solid 5px red;
}

.container {
  background: red;
}

[class*="container"] {
  background: yellow;
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

Could anyone please clarify the weights of specificity these selectors hold?

Thanks

Comment: The specificity calculator at http://specificity.keegan.st/ seems to suggest they weight the same as classes, I'm guessing they could as *pseudo-classes*

Comment: @Liam — They're attribute selectors. A psuedo-class is something like `:hover`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `#idName` is more specific than `[id*="idName"]`. But `.className` and `[class*="className"]` seem to be the same specificty.

Yes. That is what [the spec says they should be](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).

> count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a)
>
> count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)

You have an id selector, two attribute selectors, a class selector and a type selector.

Comment: Worth adding is that the specificity of an attribute selector is always the same regardless of the attribute in question, as Selectors makes no assumptions about document language semantics of attributes. The id attribute simply happens to map to an id selector in HTML, which is why `#idName` and `[id=idName]` will match the same HTML element(s).

Answer (score 0):

the CSS specificity weight has four parts,for example:0,0,0,0

- id: 0,1,0,0
- class, attribute, pseudo-classes: 0,0,1,0
- element, pseudo-elements: 0,0,0,1
- "+" or “*” or ">" :0,0,0,0

for example

```
example1:  #header .container[name="1"] div {  } 
example2:  #header div div div div div div div p p p h2::before {  }

example1_specificity = id + class + attribute + element = 0,1,2,1
example2_specificity = id + pseudo-class + element*11  = 0,1,1,11
```

the specificity will compare four parts form left to right until one is bigger than another,so example1_specificity is bigger

- when the specificity is equal,the one after another one will win
- !important will win any specificity
- 0,0,0,0 specificity will win inherit

I hope it will help you